# mongoose find() output segregation

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In below script:

```
*exports.getServer = function(req,res) {  
    Monitor.find({serverType: 'abc'}, function(err, server) {  
        return res.json(server);  
    });  
};*
```

I am getting the below result:

```
[  {  
    "_id": "587f4ec338b859cb4adee815",  
    "serverIp": "1.1.1.1",   
    "serverName": "test1",  
    "serverType": "abc",  
    "__v": 1,   
    "feed": [  "587f4ec338b859cb4adee816"  ]  
},  {
    "_id": "587f52cbb6bb030b4ccc3f72",  
    "serverIp": "1.1.1.2",  
    "serverName": "test2",  
    "serverType": "abc",  
    "__v": 1,   
    "feed": [  "587f52cbb6bb030b4ccc3f73"  ]  
}  ]
```

But i only want to fetch serverIp and serverName.
i tried using *return res.json(server.serverIp);* but it didn't work. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you;

```
*exports.getServer = function(req,res) {  
    Monitor.find({serverType: 'abc'}, {_id: 0, serverIp: 1, serverName: 1} function(err, server) {  
        return res.json(server);  
    });  
};*
```

In second parameter of `find`, you can write which fields you want to project. (`serverIp`, `serverName` in your question)

For documentation; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection

Answer (score 1):

```
// find servers with a serverType matching 'abc', selecting the `serverIp` and `serverName` fields
*exports.getServer = function(req,res) {  
    Monitor.find({serverType: 'abc'}, 'serverIp serverName', function(err, server) {  
        return res.json(server);  
    });  
};*
```

Answer (score 1):

Use projection with select method:

```
Monitor.find({serverType: 'abc'}).select('serverIp serverName').exec(function(err, servers) {
    res.json(servers);
});
```